# Write 2 lists in 2 columns of CSV file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv

I have 2 lists let's say

```
a = [1,2,3] 
b = [4,5,6]
```

I want to write them in two columns in CSV file so when I open the excel sheet I see something like this :

```
col1              col2

1                  4

2                  5

3                  6
```

How can I do this?

I used `zip(a,b)` but the result is stored in one column:

```
col1 

1 4

2 5

3 6
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `csv.Dictwriter()` to be able to specify the field names.

```
import csv

with open('numbers.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['col1', 'col2']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for i, j in zip(a, b):
        writer.writerow({'col1': i, 'col2': j})
```

Or instead of a regular `for` loop you could use `writerows` and a list comprehension:

```
writer.writerows([{'col1': i, 'col2': j} for i,j in zip(a,b)])
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `pandas` is very easy. Just:

```
import pandas as pd
```

and then:

```
In [13]: df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':a, 'col2':b})

In [14]: df
Out[14]: 
   col1  col2
0     1     4
1     2     5
2     3     6

In [15]: df.to_csv('numbers.csv', index=False)
```

Basically you are building a dataframe with your lists and then save back to `.csv`. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution, where you dont need an extra loop:

```
fieldnames = ["x_value", "y_value"]

def createcsv(fieldnames, file):
# csv for Data generation
with open(file, 'w') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    csv_writer.writeheader()

def writedata(x, y, fieldnames, file):
with open(file, 'a') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    info = {
        "x_value": x,
        "y_value": y
    }
    csv_writer.writerow(info)
```

Of course you could put those into one function, but this solution is created so that you can save your values during runtime, for example in a loop and dont have to create the fileheaders everytime again.